# How to resolve JS Promises with multiple values between parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

In the browser's console I am expecting 3 consecutive results which are: **Bears**, **Lions**, **Tigers**. in this order. What I get is only **Bears**

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return reject(new Error('no bears'));
 setTimeout(() => {
         resolve('Bears', 'Lions', 'Tigers')
   }, 1000);
})

.then(quote => {
    console.log(quote);
})
```

Comment: You're `return`ing immediately, so no timeout gets set

Comment: Resolve an array: `resolve(['Bears', 'Lions', 'Tigers'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only send a single value, consider sending as an array and spreading it at the reciever

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return reject(new Error('no bears'));
    setTimeout(() => {
         resolve(['Bears', 'Lions', 'Tigers'])
   }, 1000);
})
.then(quote => {
    console.log(...quote); // spreads to 3 items
})
```

Comment: if you use the spread operator, you can print without the `[]`

Comment: this is it! thanks

Comment: consider upvote/accept the answer if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Only the first argument to `resolve()` is actually passed to the `then` handler. You probably want to resolve with an array instead

```
resolve(['Bears', 'Lions', 'Tigers'])
```

Also, you have a `return reject()` before your `setTimeout` call so your `setTimeout` code is unreachable and it never happens.

Comment: yea I tried that but Gives out an array instead of logs. works but ive seen it work without the [ ] im 100% sure. could it be a version difference?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I'm pretty certain that `resolve` accepts only one argument. The [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) also says as much. With respect to getting an array back, what's the problem if it is an array? Array/Object is usually how you pass around multiple items in a single value in JS